# iOS: Get NSData of mp3

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, nsdata

I want to send an mp3 file from music library from my iphone over wifi. So I need a way to get NSData of mp3 file.
Is it possible? How can i access it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The current API does not allow you to access the user's media library in this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *msg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Rab" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSData* data =[[NSData alloc]init];
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:msg];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]

Comment: Or `-dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:` if it's quite large.

Comment: That would be fine, assuming [i] you can get the path to a file in the media library; [ii] you are allowed arbitrary access to files outside your app's sandbox. Neither is true. -1

Comment: OK, but how can I get the path?

Comment: you have files in your project resources?

Comment: I need files from iphone music library, not app resources

Comment: sorry but you cann't get the path from media library.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 4, you can use AVFoundation and MPMediaPickerController to export songs from the library. It's not simple, but it's doable. See http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/07/.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try using method:

(id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL